# Is static linking in Linux portable?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Is static linking in Linux portable? I mean, can I use the `-static` option in gcc and link with every dependencies statically to have a clean output from `ldd`, and expect that the resulting executable will run portably in another computer with Linux installed? Of course given that the CPU architecture and the kernel version is compatible.

Comment: Don't know why everyone is saying yes and maybe - I think no because libc will dlopen other parts of itself with hard coded paths

Comment: NSS and iconv here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140439/why-would-it-be-impossible-to-fully-statically-link-an-application probably won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: Pretty much.

This will make a binary which will run on a kernel which is the same or  compatible with the one for which the software was designed.

It may not take into account directory structure and if the binary expects to be able to load any external dependencies dynamically, that might not work.

Assuming there's nothing too fancy going on though, it will work fine.

This is approximately what Go's compiler does to enable shipment of binaries roughly anywhere.  This also is a method for making a build forward compatible if you expect to be making OS upgrades that will be disruptive.

Additionally, these static binaries could be run in a FreeBSD kernel with Linux compatibility.  As long as the kernel and user space is compatible, the binary should work.

As always, test.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The static link means it won't depend on any other library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. You won't need to worry about dynamic library dependencies. Your statically linked libraries might use system calls or other kernel interfaces that older kernels don't have, so you'll only be forward compatible (the linux kernel has a pretty strong backwards compat policy). The only thing you might need to worry about are external files that your statically linked libraries might depend on (like localization databases and such).